# First resonant frequency of a ring

Tags: acoustics

What is the first resonant frequency of a ring? It's an unusual shape because a ring doesn't have ends, it loops into itself.

Things with edges like poles and plates have a first resonant frequency equal to 1/2 wavelength because the nodes are at the edges, half of the wave fits inside. So if something is 3.4 cm long, and the material it's made from has a speed of sound the same as in air, then the first resonance is 5000 Hz because that's the 6.8 cm wavelength in that material.

But a ring does not have any edge, so is its first resonant frequency 1 wavelength as opposed to 1/2 for shapes with edges? Or does the lack of an edge have no impact on the first resonance?

For example, consider a ring with a 10 cm circumference, made from a material with a 3000 m/s speed of sound. The first resonant frequency should be 30000 Hz if it's 1 wavelength, or 15000 Hz if it's 1/2 wavelength. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key feature for getting resonance is coherence, so all you need is for the phase to return to the start as you go completely around.  So that's one full wavelength per circumference.  If you only had half a wavelength, it arrives 180 degrees out of phase, and would destructively interfere with itself.

Comment: Wouldn't this move the center of mass-if you're in phase at the "start" and out-of-phase 1/2 way around from the start--which is now pointed the opposite direction? I think you need 2 full wavelengths.

Comment: Thats is great answer,I would accept it immediately but mod told me I accept answers too soon,that I should give atleast two days time before accepting,just so you know I am not dissatisfied.

Comment: seems @JEB is right. No matter what kind of wave (in plane or out) I can only imagine 2 peaks and 2 troughs for minimum number of standing waves, with 2 nodes pi apart.

Comment: Also I was wondering about "mono-pole" modes--no angular dependence to radial distortions. This is call the 1st extension mode according to: http://www.vibrationdata.com/tutorials2/ringmode.pdf

Comment: ...actually 4 nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the claim that we must have 4 nodes.  If we deform the ring by bending upward one end, and downward the other, does it not spring back to a flat ring?  A ring cannot produce a force on its own center of mass that could move it, no matter how we deform the ring.

Comment: If you bend one side up and the other down, so it looks like an "S" from the side, it will actually have three peaks and three  troughs.

Comment: I'm talking about a horizontal ring with a vertical distortion that looks like a complete sine wave over polar angle.

Comment: Then I believe it would be planar, and not bent, so no bending oscillation. It would just be tilted. But tilting, as I'm sure you will agree, cannot be a vibration mode because then it would tilt back and forth about the axis of the nodes and spontaneously change its angular momentum. Have you looked at @JEB 's link? It confirms that the first bending modes (in plane and out) are two full wavelengths per circumference.

Comment: You might say it's not really tilted, or not only tilted, but also stretched and/or sheared. Even so, the conservation of angular momentum forbids it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you're both totally right.  The angular momentum can't oscillate, so the distortion I was imagining won't work.  It's better to think in terms of not distorting the shape but instead giving it a perturbed velocity at every point-- perturbed velocity that gives  any motion of the center of mass or any angular momentum must have those net motions subtracted until the ring is nonmoving and nonrotating.  So the problem is more complicated than I made out.